# Calling a function with different parameters depending on argparse value

Tags: python, argparse

I need to form **help** for my program in a following style:

- `run.py -h` -> generic help
- `run.py module1 -h` -> help text for module generated by
  `build_help(mod)`
- `run.py module1 submodule1 -h` -> help text for given submodule (`submodule1`), also
  generated by function.

The 1st part is quite simple. The 3rd is the extension of 2nd. But I can't to implement 2nd part.

I tried to use `subparser`, but as I understood, I should write too many code to implement this. For example:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_module1 = subparsers.add_parser('module1')
parser_module1.set_defaults(func=build_help)
```

and iterate last 2 lines for every module.

I also can implement if using **only one** subparser:

```
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
parser_module = subparsers.add_parser('module')
parser_module.add_argument('name', help='Module name')
parser_module.set_defaults(func=build_help)
```

But then I'll be forced to modify 2nd part as

```
run.py module module1 -h
```

How can I implement 2nd part of help if I don't want to change calling pattern (I need to leave `run.py module1 -h` pattern)?

**UPD.** I know, there is many external libraries probably doing this. For example, [getopt](http://python.active-venture.com/lib/module-getopt.html), [docopt](http://docopt.org/), [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/), [consoleargs](https://github.com/muromec/consoleargs) etc. But I really wouldn't want to create external dependencies for this task.

Comment: I don't know if you are doing this for fun or for an actual application, but you may want to have a look at libraries such as click, which provides a nice way of doing what you want to do

Comment: Why not use [docopt](http://docopt.org/) ? You'll have to define the usage for your command line app and then you get automatically generated parser for it.

Comment: @FlavianHautbois, I'm doing this for actual application. I really don't want to add new external dependencies to my system for this task.

Comment: Well I encourage you to :)

Answer (score 1):

`argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)` turns off the automatic `help` mechanism.  In other words, it does not automatically create an argument that responds to `-h`.  You can then define your own `-h` argument.

When I create a regular parser:

```
In [56]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

In [57]: parser
Out[57]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipython2.7', usage=None, description=None, version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)

In [59]: parser._actions
Out[59]: [_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None)]
```

Its `_actions` list includes the `-h` action.  Look at the `argparse._HelpAction` class to see what it does special.  Basically it displays the help and calls `sys.exit`.

For example I can create a action that behaves the same but responds to `-q`:

```
In [62]: parser.add_argument('-q',action='help')
Out[62]: _HelpAction(option_strings=['-q'], dest='q', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [63]: parser.parse_args(['-q'])
usage: ipython2.7 [-h] [-q]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -q
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 0

To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
```

Subparsers issue a different help because the main parser encounters the subparser name before it encounters the `-h`.  So it's the `subparser` that is issuing the help, not the main parser.

Hopefully this description gives you the building blocks to construct what you need.  We could dialog more if you need more detailed help.

Notice I use `ipython` for my examples.  It uses `argparse`.  But it catches the `-h/help` in `sys.argv` before calling the parser.  Thus it has complete control over the help message.

Another customization route - define your own `parser.format_help` function.